# pip install pandas not working even though it seems I have got pip

Tags: python, pandas, pip

I have installed `Python` on `Windows` though it is not in my `PATH` variable. I want to use `pandas`

When I do `import pandas`, I get error that `pandas` modules can't be found
When I do `pip install pandas`, I get error that `pip` is not a command
When I do `python -m pip --version`, I can see `pip`

Why am I not able to use `pip`?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had to first update `pip (optional I think) -` python -m pip install -U pip`and then use it like this`python -m pip install pandas`